# Reservar memoria dinamica en char

Tags: c

Estoy realizando una lectura de un archivo.txt en `C`, mi duda es como (o de que manera) se podría realizar el almacenamiento de la información que obtengo de un `.txt` en una variable de tipo `char` sin saber el tamaño exacto de dicho `char` en el archivo de texto.

Es decir, si tengo lo siguiente en el `.txt`:

```
www.stackoverflow.com
```

Debería reservar 22 bytes, `21` para los caracteres en sí y 1 más para el `0` final. Es decir, realizar lo siguiente:

```c
char url[22];
```

Pero en el caso de tener en el `.txt` un `url` (ya que en mi archivo estoy trabajando con URLs) que no sé la cantidad exacta a reservar, por ejemplo:

```
www.urlaleatorio.com.ve
```

¿De que manera podría reservar memoria (si es que se puede, realmente no lo sé) dependiendo de dicho "url" en este caso?

- Código en lenguaje `C`:

```c
int main( ) {

    FILE * archivo = fopen( "url.txt", "r" );

    if( archivo == NULL ) {
        perror( "Error en la apertura del archivo" );
        return 1;
    }

    char url[22];

    while( 1 ) {
        fscanf( archivo, "%s%s", url );

        if( feof( archivo ) != 0 ) {
            break;
        }

        printf( "%s %s\n", url );
    }

    fclose( archivo );
    printf( "\nSe ha leido el archivo correctamente...\n" );

    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: Puedes hacer uso de esta biblioteca: [LibraryList](https://github.com/MrDave1999/LibraryList), esta librería te permite manejar estructuras de datos (`ArrayList` o `LinkedList`) sin tener la necesidad de preocuparte por el tamaño de un arreglo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Poderse, se puede. Aunque *la cosa* se complica un poco.

La lógica es sencilla: según vas obteniendo datos, compruebas si has llagado al último (usando un carácter especial: `0` o `\n`, por ejemplo).

Si tu *buffer* se llena, y no ha llegado ese *indicador-de-final*, pues aumentas el buffer. Podrías reservar otro y copiar ... o llamar directamente a [`realloc( )`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc), que hace justamente eso (con ciertas optimizaciones).

Un pequeño ejemplo: vamos a leer desde la entrada estardar, y lo vamos almacenando en un *buffer*, que iremos redimensionando *sobre la marcha*. Al final del programa, se imprimirá ese *buffer*.

Dejaremos de leer datos al llegar a un <kbd>TABULADOR</kbd>, eso será nuestra marca de final:

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Buffer {
  size_t size;
  char *begin;
  char *end;
  char *ptr;
};

struct Buffer createBuffer( ) {
  struct Buffer result = { 0 };

  return result;
}

void resizeBuffer( struct Buffer *buff ) {
  if( !( buff->size ) ) {
    // Primera vez. Un número arbitrario cualquiera.
    buff->size = 10;
    buff->ptr = malloc( 10 );
    buff->begin = buff->ptr;
    buff->end = buff->begin + 10;
  } else {
    ptrdiff_t offset = buff->ptr - buff->begin;

    buff->size *= 2;
    buff->begin = realloc( buff->begin, buff->size );
    buff->ptr = buff->begin + offset;
    buff->end = buff->begin + buff->size;
  }
}

void finishBuffer( struct Buffer *buff ) {
  if( buff->ptr == buff->end ) {
    resizeBuffer( buff );
  }

  *( buff->ptr ) = 0;
}


void appendToBuffer( char data, struct Buffer *buff ) {
  if( buff->ptr == buff->end ) {
    resizeBuffer( buff );
  }

  *( buff->ptr ) = data;
  ++( buff->ptr );
}

int main( ) {
  struct Buffer buffer = createBuffer( );

  // Leemos un caracter de la entrada estandard.
  while( 1 ) {
    int readed = getchar( );

    if( readed == '\t' ) {
      break;
    }

    appendToBuffer( (char)readed, &buffer );
  }

  finishBuffer( &buffer );

  printf( "%s\n", buffer.begin );

  return 0;
}
```

Piensa que este proceso no es lo mas rápido del mundo (ni el ejemplo está optimizado, he intentado que sea claro y útil mas que en su eficiencia). En tu caso, dices que recibes desde *HTTP*. Este protocolo **puede** indicar el tamaño del elemento enviado. Podrías sacar provecho de esto para reservar tu *buffer* de una sola vez.